# Examples of static's utility?

Tags: c#, function, class, methods, static

I navigated the site and found no topic that asked (or gave) specific examples of static's utility on C#. I am a beginner and wanted to find given cases in which the usefulness of statics are proved, in order to go further than the conceptual understanding of what a static class/method/etc is. I know only of one or two examples, such as being able to create a method that produces an object or a value when ran, but keep that one value "for ever", by the means of removing the new values created (when the script runs again) if a value has been created before. The code for that is this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicPlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    static MusicPlayerScript instance = null;

    // Use this for initialization


    void Start () {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            print("Duplicate self-destructing");
        } else
        {
            instance = this;
            GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

What other examples could anybody give me? Thank you!

Comment: This question is too broad. The answer requires a book chapter.

Comment: [_"The Static keyword can be applied on classes, variables, methods, properties, operators, events and constructors."_](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-static) As @MarkBenningfield said - that makes your question very broad - you will find lots of information by use of google or looking at C# books. More examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Comment: *"I navigated the forum..."* Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site. There's a difference. Please check the site [tour].

Comment: Why would it be to broad? I am not requesting deep explanation, not even any type of conceptual insight. Only one or two examples, such as "well you could do such and such with statics, to improve this and that on your code/program".

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one. If you have something to do that is not directly related to a specific object of the class you want to group it into, you define a static method. For example if you need a very specific helper function that acts on one of your properties but not on the whole object.

A static member variable allows you to define for example a singled-out object of your class. For example if your class is "Scene" and you want an all-encompassing Scene-object named World, you would define static Scene World.

In many ways statics can be considered what has been known as globals in older programming languages. What makes them less dangerous than globals is proper namespace resolution. You don't see them everywhere unless you know how to get to them, ie. on which namespace path.

Comment: I still consider `static` vastly overused and mildly dangerous because it can create coupling that can be hard to spot and additionally makes unit testing harder. It has its uses of course, but I've often seen it abused.

Comment: Probably true. I don't use it alot at least. Usually only private static.